# Find the two points on the x-axis corresponding to the intersections for a cdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, binomial-cdf

The corresponding `r code` is given below.

```
theta <- seq(0,1, length = 10)
CD_theta <- function(x, p, n){
  1 - pbinom(x, size = n, prob = p) + 1 / 2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = p)
}
```

Then I graphed the data as follows :

```
mytheta <- CD_theta(5, theta, 10)
df <- data.frame(theta = theta, mytheta = mytheta)
ggplot(df, aes(x = theta, y = mytheta)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, col = "steelblue") +
  ylab("H(Theta)") +
  xlab("Theta")
```

The corresponding graph is given below.
[image]

As you can see there are two horizontal lines (graphed in red) and the two vertical lines (graphed in black). I need to find the two points on the x-axis corresponding to the intersections for a H(theta).

I used the `locator()` function in `r` to compute the two x intercepts for a single iteration. I would like iterate the above for 1000 times, so it is really tedious approach find them separately.

are there any other `r` functions can be used find these two x intercept points?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numerical approach using `optimize` function:

```r
library(reprex)

theta <- seq(0,1, length = 10)
CD_theta <- function(x, p, n){
  1 - pbinom(x, size = n, prob = p) + 1 / 2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = p)
}

# Create a function to compute the difference between the "y" you want 
# and the "y" computed with CD_theta function 
# then try to minimize the output of this new function : 
# get the theta value corresponding to this "y"

my_fn <- function(theta_loc, y, x, n) { 
  # the function to optimize
  abs(y - CD_theta(x, theta_loc, n)) # dont forget abs (absolute)
}

# Then use optimize function to compute the theta value 
# between a given interval : c(0,1) in this case
# Note that you can directly modify here the values of y, x and n
v1 <- optimize(my_fn, c(0, 1), y = 0.025, x = 5, n = 10)$`minimum` 
v2 <- optimize(my_fn, c(0, 1), y = 0.975, x = 5, n = 10)$`minimum` 

# print the results
v1 # 0.025
#> [1] 0.2120079
v2 # 0.975
#> [1] 0.7879756
```

Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the discretisation of your curve a bit, this gets fairly simple:

```
theta <- seq(0,1, length = 100) # increase length here for more precision on point locations
CD_theta <- function(x, p, n){
  1 - pbinom(x, size = n, prob = p) + 1 / 2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = p)
}

mytheta <- CD_theta(5, theta, 10)
df <- data.frame(theta = theta, mytheta = mytheta)
ggplot(df, aes(x = theta, y = mytheta)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, col = "steelblue") +
  ylab("H(Theta)") +
  xlab("Theta")

points <- data.frame(x=c(theta[which.min(abs(mytheta - .975))], # find which point is the nearer
                         theta[which.min(abs(mytheta - .025))]),
                     y=c(.975,.025))

ggplot(df, aes(x = theta, y = mytheta)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, col = "steelblue") +
  ylab("H(Theta)") +
  xlab("Theta") + 
  geom_point(data=points,aes(y=y, x=x), size=5, col="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the exact `Theta` and `HTheta` values, independent of the grid size (here `N = 10`), apply `uniroot` to the `CD_theta` function.

```
CD_theta <- function(x, p, n) {
    1  -  pbinom (x, size = n, prob = p) + 
    1/2 * dbinom(x, size = n, prob = p)
}

u1 = uniroot(function(p) CD_theta(5, p, 10) - 0.025, c(0, 1))
u2 = uniroot(function(p) CD_theta(5, p, 10) - 0.975, c(0, 1))
(Theta1 = u1$root)  # 0.2119934
(Theta2 = u2$root)  # 0.7880066
```

But if the discretization (with `N = 10`) is important for you, then perform a linear interpolation on this function between grid points.

```
theta <- seq(0, 1, length = 10)
mytheta <- CD_theta(5, theta, 10)
f <- approxfun(theta, mytheta, method = "linear", 0.0, 1.0)

u1 = uniroot(function(p) f(p) - 0.025, c(0, 1))
u2 = uniroot(function(p) f(p) - 0.975, c(0, 1))
(Theta1 = u1$root)  # 0.2015638
(Theta2 = u2$root)  # 0.7984362
```